# Get current object URL with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage uses object that are external websites (or other web pages).
for example:

```
<object data="external.html"></object>
```

on this page (external.html), the URL changes according to the navigation of the user. I want to know if there's a way to get the new URL using JavaScript/jQuery.

For example, when using:

```
<object data="www.google.com"></object>
```

If the user went from `www.google.com` to `www.google.com/#q=JavaScript`, I would like to get the second URL.
This won't work with Google, but theoretically speaking.

Alternatively, is there a way to display an external website and have access to the changing URL? Meaning, having a div populated by another website and somehow get the URL (after the user navigated through the site and the URL changes) with JavaScript/jQuery/some other way?
No need to manipulate this URL, just read access.

Comment: If those external pages aren't yours, I would think not. Unless maybe you opened those pages "inside" your website. Otherwise, once they navigate away from your website, your code will no longer run.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect current URL using **location.href** and then collect object using its ID and then append data as current URL to it.

Answer (score 0):

This should not possible as it will violate cross domain security policies. The same restriction is there with `iframe`, so I guess it applies to `object` as well.

If it is same domain, you can try getting the current URL from `contentWindow` or `contentDocument`

```
<objectElement>.contentWindow.location.href
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for. You can split the url.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var urlSplit = 'www.google.com/#q=JavaScript'.split('/');
  alert(urlSplit[urlSplit.length - 1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  Click Me
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').click(function() {
  var urlSplit = 'www.google.com/#q=JavaScript'.split('/');
  alert(urlSplit[urlSplit.length - 1]);
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  Click Me
</button>
```